# Create executable jar file in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, package

I`m using Spring Tool Suite 4 (4.12.0.RELEASE) with Java 8 and I have a Spring Boot project with the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.swagger-code-gen-v2</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-code-gen-v2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>swagger-code-gen-v2</name>
    <description>REST Client using Swagger codegen</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <swagger.codegen.version>3.0.34</swagger.codegen.version>       
        <swagger-annotations-version>2.0.0</swagger-annotations-version>
        <spring-web-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-web-version>
        <jackson-version>2.13.0</jackson-version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <junit-version>4.13.1</junit-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP client: Spring RestTemplate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-web-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>                    
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-contacts-spec-json</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/contacts-spec.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</output>

                            <apiPackage>com.hubapi.contacts.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.hubapi.contacts.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.hubapi.contacts</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <sourceFolder>restclient</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-companies-spec-json</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/companies-spec.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</output>

                            <apiPackage>com.hubapi.companies.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.hubapi.companies.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.hubapi.companies</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <sourceFolder>restclient</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-schemas-spec-json</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas-spec.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</output>

                            <apiPackage>com.hubapi.schemas.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.hubapi.schemas.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.hubapi.schemas</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <sourceFolder>restclient</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-objects-spec-json</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/objects-spec.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</output>

                            <apiPackage>com.hubapi.objects.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.hubapi.objects.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.hubapi.objects</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <sourceFolder>restclient</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-auth-spec-json</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/auth-spec.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</output>

                            <apiPackage>com.hubapi.auth.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.hubapi.auth.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.hubapi.auth</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <sourceFolder>restclient</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Running "maven clean compile" works fine. However when I run "maven clean package" in order to create executable jar file I got the exception:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-10 10:55:57.424  INFO 9716 --- [           main] c.s.SwaggerCodeGenV2ApplicationTests     : Starting SwaggerCodeGenV2ApplicationTests using Java 1.8.0_171 on DESKTOP-LUL14QL with PID 9716 (started by Owner in C:\swagger-code-gen-v2)
2022-08-10 10:55:57.426  INFO 9716 --- [           main] c.s.SwaggerCodeGenV2ApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-10 10:55:57.926  WARN 9716 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
2022-08-10 10:55:57.935  INFO 9716 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-10 10:55:57.964 ERROR 9716 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132) [spring-boot-test-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at 

(...)
```

I`m new on maven and spring boots so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do not try to handle versions on your own. Let Spring Boot do it's work.. as already answered by Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downgraded `spring-web` to `4.3.9.RELEASE`. Spring Boot 2.7.2 requires `5.3.x`. You should remove the `<version>${spring-web-version}</version>` declaratation from the dependencies in your pom and allow Spring Boot's dependency management to control the version.

You can also remove `<version>${jackson-version}</version>` as Spring Boot manages the version of Jackson for you as well.

A list of all of the dependency versions that Spring Boot manages [can be found in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.coordinates).